# How to get flexbox to respect removed elements?

Tags: css, webkit, flexbox

I'm using [Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/) to achieve equal height columns in WebKit browsers.

I'm using this CSS...

```
ol {
   display: -webkit-box;   
}

ol li {
   width: 100px;
   background: #ccc;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;    
}
```

...and this HTML...

```
<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ol>
​
```

...which produces...

[image: Example]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqU2E/).

As you can see, the three elements are the height of their tallest sibling (the first `li`).

If I removed the tallest element, I'd expect there to be a reflow in which the other elements became the height of the next tallest element.

What I expected...

[image: :)]

What actually happened...

[image: :(]

As an interesting note, when you start inspecting the elements in Web Inspector, the problem corrects itself. Perhaps I could reproduce this *self-correcting* by explicitly triggering a browser repaint, but I'd prefer not to have to introduce JavaScript for what should be handled 100% in the CSS.

Is there a way to tell Flexbox to shrink/recalculate when sibling elements are removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out...

Add these two properties to the `li` elements...

```
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
min-height: 0;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8XQJ/).

Now, when you remove the first element, the others shrink to fit.