# -webkit-box not shrinking

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to create dynamic layout with `-webkit-box`.

When children of box grow everything is working as expected - box grows to accommodate.
Unfortunately when children are resized back, box remains in enlarged state. This happens only when there are multiple children.

Is this by design ? Can I workaround that (without javascript)?

I'm using Chrome 22.0.1229.39 beta-m.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mwisnicki/s8z8N/) jsfiddle.

Comment: I asked [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10747236/31671), if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: -webkit-flex;`. Unfortunately it's only on Chrome 21+ but I doubt that's an issue since you're using `-webkit-box` already. http://jsfiddle.net/s8z8N/3/